# Filter and combine 2 lists into one with the condition

Tags: python, list

I have 2 lists. You need to filter and combine these list items into one. So that the elements of the first match the values of the second and vice versa, the second=the first. At the same time, if there are values in the second list where the last character contains a dash, then you need to consider it correct and save the choose from the first list (without the final character).

```
lst_col = ['DATE', 'CODE', 'STATUS', 'COST-', 'POSITION', 'NUMBER', 'TIMESTAMP-']
lst_row = [['DATE', '07/01/2021'], ['CODE', '1234'], ['OFFSET', '12333'], ['COST--', '55'], ['POSITION-', '25'], ['TIMESTAMP--', '1625885564']]
```

The result will be as follows

```
[['DATE', '01/07/2021'], ['CODE', '1234'], ['COST-', '55'], ['POSITION', '25'], ['TIMESTAMP-', '1625885564']]
```

I tried to create a set (elements with dashes) for the second list, and then filter it, but it didn't work, because I tried to write compactly, without using several loops.

Comment: *"You need to "* - No I don't. Goodbye.

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
new_list = [[f for f in lst_row if f[0].replace("-", "") == i.replace("-", "")] for i in lst_col]
```

Comment: A little wrong. The resulting list must contain the elements of the first list, if they match (`[['DATE', '01/07/2021'], ['CODE', '1234'], ['COST-', '55'], ['POSITION', '25'], ['TIMESTAMP-', '1625885564']]`)

Comment: I wouldn't have written if I hadn't checked the result. And it's clear from the code that the result is a little wrong. Current result `[[['DATE', '07/01/2021']], [['CODE', '1234']], [], [['COST--', '55']], [['POSITION-', '25']], [], [['TIMESTAMP--', '1625885564']]]` Items not from the list lst_col. The desired result `[['DATE', '01/07/2021'], ['CODE', '1234'], ['COST-', '55'], ['POSITION', '25'], ['TIMESTAMP-', '1625885564']]`